# Which function in bottle provides infinite wait request?

Tags: python, bottle

I want to use Bottle framework for my Python web projects. I am only a beginner in this. So, first of all I want to understand how it works.

Simple app looks like:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

run(host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I found `run` function in `bottle.py` but I don't understand where are the blocks of code which expect requests from the browser. Maybe I don't understand something. That is why maybe you could explain me basic things of this meсhanism.

Comment: `bottle` cannot do any requests _from_ the browser. It's a _server_. It answers the requests of browsers. Only _client-side_ software can send requests 'from the browser', but `bottle` is a server itself, it just does its best to send data to the browser, that's all.

Comment: What actually do you want? Please provide more information. The information you provided in the form of syntax of code is even more confusing. Some explanation will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is request - response based. 
Request --> Browser,  Response --> Server (the server is bottle in your case).
 The communication from the browser ends once the server served a response to the client (Browser). That is the regular HTTP way. 
If you want to maintain a continuous connection between the browser and the server for example to give real-time updates to the browser, (the browser does not have to ask for updates, the server sends them to the browser) one way to do it would be Websockets.

Here is the documentation for Websockets in Bottle: 
https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html#finally-websockets

Comment: Ok, thank you.I don't want to maintain a continuous connection. I just want  to find a function in **bottle.py** which provides single communication with browser. And I want to undersand how server respond of which requests from the browser, if connection is not continious.

Comment: When you run bootle, a development server starts. run(host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True). This starts a local development server on port 5000. You can reach it when you type localhost:5000 in the adress bar of your browser. When you go to the url localhost:5000/hello your hello function of the server will  be called from the browser and the server responds to the request.